# How do I hide the Junk Email Folder in Outlook 2011

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

I get all my emails through gmail which has great spam filtering so I have turned off the outlook 2011 for mac junk email filtering but I can't seem to get rid of the Junk Email folder on the left hand side I would like not see it anyway I can delete it or turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Junk E-mail folder is a system folder like Sent Items, Inbox, Deleted Items, so it cannot be removed or hidden.